# Django JSON Eroor: "list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: json, django, list

I have following `JSON` which contain employee data.

```
all_emp = {"success":true,"data":{"users":
[[{"employeeId":"6","firstName":"Abhishek","lastName":"Amit"},
.
.
.
{"employeeId":"CT045","firstName":"Daniel","lastName":"Swamy"}
]]}}
```

I have two table `Ideas` and `Likes`.

I want to display name of peoples who liked that idea.

In likes table I have stored `user_id`(who liked idea) and `idea_id` is a foreign key

I want to replace `user_id` of like table to name of that user using `JSON`

Following is my code in view file..

```
latest_ideas_list = Ideas.objects.order_by('-date_added')

for i in latest_ideas_list:
    people_like = Likes.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True).filter(idea_id=i.idea_id)
    for person in people_like:
        if any(d["employeeId"] == person for d in all_emp['data']['users']):
            person = d['firstName'] + ' '+ d['lastName']

    i.likelist = people_like
```

Following is template..

```
{% for person in anidea.likelist %}
   <span>{{person}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting error "list indices must be integers, not str"

I am new to python and django. Need help please.

Comment: Users is a list of lists of dicts, for some reason.

Comment: Yes. I am getting that using external web service.

Answer (score 1):

First of all here I guess `all_emp['data'].['users']` must be `all_emp['data']['users']` and `d["employeeId"] == person for d in all_emp['data']['users']` here d is a list with only one element and that element then have all employer data.

So as a quick fix you can try this:

`d["employeeId"] == person for d in all_emp['data']['users'][0]`

Comment: Not getting error, but i am not able to replace user_id with employee name yet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my issue with following code.

```
p_result = []
for person in people_like:                
    for d in all_emp['data']['users'][0]:
       if str(person) in d["employeeId"]:
           person = d["firstName"] + ' '+ d["lastName"]
           p_result.append(person)

i.likelist = p_result
```